# How to get selenium and xvfb to work in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, selenium, xvfb

My goal is to run my test in behat which has a driver for selenium using mink library.
I am able to get this done on my local dev machine. However on my server I need to use
xvfb for headless testing.

I read [this article](http://www.installationpage.com/selenium/how-to-run-selenium-headless-firefox-in-ubuntu/). However below are the errors:

> - Xvfb :10 -ac
>     I get an error
>     [dix] Could not init font path element /var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType, removing from list!

I searched; there are many articles on this, but nothing really worked.

[Here is an example article which I read](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342376/missing-fonts-in-xvfb).

> - root@dezoomify:~# export DISPLAY=:10
>     root@dezoomify:~# firefox
>     Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":10".

and I tried using Firefox then I get **"RANDR"** missing.

Please advise as to what I can do here.

I have tried:

1. installing wine
2. sudo apt-get -y install x-ttcidfont-conf cabextract ttf-mscorefonts-installer
3. sudo dpkg-reconfigure x-ttcidfont-conf

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run xvfb and Chrome on a remote Ubuntu server through SSH. I also met the exactly same errors:

1. Could not init font path element /var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType, removing from list!
2. Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":10".

Seems neither is critical error. You can check xvfb and Chrome are running in background by command 'ps'. So you can safely ignore them and redirect standard output and standard error to /dev/null